# Script to replace the letters with diacritics Á, É, Í, ... by A, E, I,

Tags: vbscript

Can you tell me what I need change in this script to get this output?

"The output is Acailandia"

```
Function EliminarAcentos(texto)

Dim i, s1, s2
s1 = "ÁÀÉÈÍÏÓÒÚÜáàèéíïóòúüñç"
s2 = "AAEEIIOOUUaaeeiioouunc"
If Len(texto) <> 0 Then
    For i = 1 To Len(s1)
        texto = Replace(texto, Mid(s1,i,1), Mid(s2,i,1))
    Next
End If

EliminarAcentos = texto

End Function
```

c:> cscript script1 Açailândia

Answer (score 2):

If you are lucky (comparable codepages/encodings for script and console), adding

1. â to s1 and a to s2
2. "The output is " to the command line

will give you:

```
cscript 36728122.vbs "The output is Açailândia"
The output is Acailandia
```

**Update wrt comment:**

Main code:

```
WScript.Echo EliminarAcentos(WScript.Arguments(0))
```

**Full code:**

```
Option Explicit

Function EliminarAcentos(texto)
    Dim i, s1, s2
    s1 = "ÁÀÉÈÍÏÓÒÚÜáàèéíïóòúüñçâ"
    s2 = "AAEEIIOOUUaaeeiioouunca"
    If Len(texto) <> 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Len(s1)
            texto = Replace(texto, Mid(s1,i,1), Mid(s2,i,1))
        Next
    End If
    EliminarAcentos = texto
End Function

WScript.Echo EliminarAcentos(WScript.Arguments(0))
```

Comment: Running the script I get no output:
C:\Work>cscript acento.vbs açailândia
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Versão 5.8
Copyright (C) 1996-2001 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

Comment: How can I pass the word like a parameter to the script ?

Comment: I´m doing this, without success (I don´t have an output):
C:\Work>cscript eliminaracento.vbs   açailândia

Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Versão 5.8
Copyright (C) 1996-2001 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer - Now I understood your answer and i´ts working fine. Best regards.